# How can I add a new listbox item foreach List<string>

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Using the Prism Library I've setup a Model inheriting BindableBase (INotiftyPropertyChanged).

Then In the ViewModel, in the constructor I create a new object of my ReadConnections class which will return a List of connection names from a local XML file.

Then I set the Connections property from the method GetIdNode in the ReadConnections class.

Finally I bind the Listbox ItemSource to the Connections property. When I run the application the Listbox is not populated with any listbox items. I'm not sure if binding ItemSource is correct, I've never bound anything to a listbox before.

Model Class:

```
public class LoginDialogModel : BindableBase
{
    private List<string> _connections;

    public List<string> Connections
    {
        get { return _connections; }
        set { _connections = value; }
    }
}
```

ViewModel Class Constructor:

```
    public LoginDialogVM()
    {
        ReadConnections read = new ReadConnections();
        LoginModel.Connections = read.GetIdNodes();
    }
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="247" Margin="10,10,0,0" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" ItemsSource="{Binding LoginModel.Connections}"/>
```

Comment: You need some kind of change notification in your list and List<T> does not implement such an event use ObeservableCollection<T> instead.

Comment: Have you setup the datacontext? Also, use SetProperty from BindableBase for notification.

Comment: Both suggestions worked. The Observable Collection worked and I also didn't realize that I left out SetProperty which works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your propery (with BindableBase inheriting) should looks like this

```
public class LoginDialogModel : BindableBase
{
    private List<string> _connections;

    public List<string> Connections
    {
        get { return _connections; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _connections,value); }
    }
}
```

And as you see, SetProperty method takes care about NotifyProperty